# dialog.showMessageBoxSync(null, options) getting hidden

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, electron

I have an Electron app. If I use `dialog.showmessageBoxSync` normally it has to wait for user input. The options are: close, cancel or ok.

It is working fine but if I click outside of the dialog box (anywhere inside my app) then this message box hidden. I'm unable to click on any option.

How can I make the message box stay focused until the user chooses a button to click or closes the dialog box? The user should be forced to respond to the message box before continuing to work in the rest of the app.

```
dialog.showMessageBoxSync({
                    type: "info",
                    buttons: ["Ok,", "Cancel"],
                    defaultId: 0,
                    title: "",
                    message:""
                    cancelId: 1,
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest passing in a parent window

From the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxsyncbrowserwindow-options)

> The browserWindow argument allows the dialog to attach itself to a
>   parent window, making it modal.

---

```
 const iconPath = upath.toUnix(upath.join(__dirname, "app", "assets", "icon.png"));
    const dialogIcon = nativeImage.createFromPath(iconPath);

    var options = {
        type: 'question',
        buttons: ['&Yes', '&No'],
        title: 'Confirm Quit',
        icon: dialogIcon,
        normalizeAccessKeys: true,
        message: 'Do you really want to close the application?'
    };

    const win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
    dialog.showMessageBox(win, options)
        .then((choice) => {
            if (choice.response === 0) {
                quitApplication();
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('ERROR', err);
        });
```